# Why do we use $\frac12(v_f+v_i)$ in the kinematic equations?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, displacement

I find it confusing that we have to use the average of the velocity instead of the final velocity. Can someone explain to me why

$$s = \frac12(v_f+v_i)t$$

is true?

Comment: Hiint: [The area under a trapezoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid#Area) gives us displacement.

Comment: Be aware that this equation only holds when the acceleration is constant.

Comment: Who says "we have to use the average ...?" We can, but there's no requirement. You should cite your sources rather than make random statements. What you are saying may be your personal impressions.

Answer (score 2):

I really wish they would teach some very basic calculus as an introduction to physics.

Anyway, we you need to realize is that the displacement of an object is mathematically equivalent to the area under the velocity vs. time curve.

[image: fig1]

So the kinematic relationship is just the *area under a trapezoid* if you remember your geometry.

$$ s = \frac{v_f+v_i}{2} (t_f -t_i ) $$

But why? well in physics you say on average during this time frame it moves with $v_a = \frac{v_f+v_i}{2}$ speed, and so $s$ is the distance traveled under constant speed $v_a$.

Geometrically, if you slice a trapezoid along its average height, and move the leftover triangle under the cut you can create a rectangle (of known height).

[image: fig2]

The final question on this topic, is why is displacement equals the area under the speed curve? The answer is that by definition speed is the slope of the displacement curve, and calculus shows us that area under the curve is the inverse operation of slope of a curve.

Comment: "I really wish they would teach some very basic calculus as an introduction to physics." In fairness, every introductory class I've ever seen or been a part of *does* do this.  Whether they do it particularly *well* is a different question.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the result depends on the special case of "constant acceleration". Graphical interpretations are generally good supplements to merely equations.

Comment: @J.Murray "In fairness, every introductory class I've ever seen or been a part of *does* do this." Unfortunately, that isn't true anywhere close to everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

(This supplements the graphical answer by @JAlex, which implicitly assumes constant acceleration.)

In general, the *physics-textbook definition for average-velocity* is,
$$\Delta x \stackrel{textbook\ def}{=} v_{avg} \Delta t.$$
For simplicity, set $t_i=0$, and let $s=\Delta x$.

Then $$s=v_{avg} t_f.$$

When the **acceleration is constant**,

starting with the *real definition for "average velocity"*

(**the time-average of the velocity** *[not "half the sum of the initial and final velocities"]*),

we have

\begin{align}
v_{avg} 
&\stackrel{def}{=}\frac{\int_0^{t_f} dt\ v}{\int_0^{t_f} dt }\quad
\stackrel{textbook\ def}{=} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t }\\\
&\stackrel{constant\ a}{=}\frac{\int_0^{t_f} dt\ (v_i+at)}{\int_0^{t_f} dt }\\
&\stackrel{constant\ a}{=}\frac{v_i t_f+\frac{1}{2}at_f^2}{t_f }\\
&\stackrel{constant\ a}{=}v_i +\frac{1}{2}at_f\\
&\stackrel{constant\ a}{=}v_i +\frac{1}{2}(v_f-v_i)\\
v_{avg}&\stackrel{constant\ a}{=}\frac{1}{2}(v_f+v_i)\\
\end{align}
Thus,
$$s \stackrel{constant\ a}{=} \left(\frac{1}{2} (v_f+v_i)\right)t_f$$
If the acceleration isn't constant, then this expression derived for $v_{avg}$ does not hold.

So, this expression is useful for constant acceleration if you already know the initial and final velocity and the duration of the trip. (It could be derived from presumably more basic kinematics equations for constant acceleration:
$x_f-x_i=v_i \Delta t +\frac{1}{2}a_i (\Delta t)^2$
and
$v_f-v_i=a_i \Delta t$.)